# Apache Camel: how to isolate logic into testable atomic routes

Tags: apache-camel, atomic

Let's consider the following use case:

- a set of providers pushes data in a corresponding directory on a local server (e.g. P1 pushes data into data/P1, P2 into data/P2, etc.)
- each provider has its own generation rules (e.g. P1 generates plain txt files, P2 generates archives, P3 generates encrypted files, etc.)
- on a Spring Boot application running on the server, each provider has its own Camel route which, every 10 minutes, reads from the corresponding directory (e.g. R1 reads from("file:data/P1"), R2 reads from("file:data/P2"),
  etc.)
- the given provider can also combine rules (e.g. P4 generates archives containing encrypted data)
- depending on the route, read data is then processed accordingly in order to move plain txt files to a target directory (e.g. R2 unzips data and moves it, R4 unzips data, decrypts the extraction result and moves it, etc.)

As soon as more routes are implemented, it immediately appears obvious that most of the code is duplicated and can be extracted; in fact, since rules can be combined, each data elaboration could be seen as an atomic operation, available for the given route.
Let's consider, for instance, the following atomic operations:

- unzip
- decrypt
- move

So, here's how those routes could look like:

R1

```
from("file:data/P1")
  .to("file:destination")
```

R2

```
from("file:data/P2")
  // UNZIP LOGIC HERE
  .to("file:destination")
```

R3

```
from("file:data/P3")
  // DECRYPT LOGIC HERE
  .to("file:destination")
```

R4

```
from("file:data/P4")
  // UNZIP LOGIC HERE
  // DECRYPT LOGIC HERE
  .to("file:destination")
```

Since I want to extract common logic, I see two main options here (with corresponding R4 resulting code):

- extract the logic into a custom component

```
from("file:data/P4")
  // FOR EACH FILE
  .to("my-custom-component:unzip")
  .to("my-custom-component:decrypt")
  .to("file:destination")
```

- extract the logic into smaller routes

```
from("file:data/P4")
  // FOR EACH FILE
  .to("direct:my-unzip-route")
  .to("direct:my-decrypt-route")
  .to("file:destination")
```

(of course, this is a *super simplification*, but it's just to give you the big picture).

Between those two options, I prefer the latter, which allows me to quickly reuse Camel EIPs (e.g. unmarshal().pgp()):

```
from("file:data/P4")
  .to("direct:my-unzip-route")
  .to("direct:my-decrypt-route")
  .to("file:destination");

from("direct:my-unzip-route")
  // LOGIC
  .unmarshal().zip()
  // MORE LOGIC
  ;

from("direct:my-decrypt-route")
  // LOGIC
  .unmarshal().pgp()
  // MORE LOGIC
  ;
```

**First question**: since the given sub-route changes the original set of files (e.g. unzip could transform one archive into 100 files), would it be better to use *enrich()* instead of *to()*?

**Second question**: what am I supposed to route between those sub-routes? Right now, due to implementation details not explained here for simplicity, I'm routing a collection of file names so, instead of the *from("file:data/P4")* I have a *from("direct:read-P4")* which receives a list of file names as input and then propagates this list to the given sub-routes; each sub-route, starting from the list of file names, applies its own logic, generating new files and *returning* a body with the updated list (e.g. receives {"test.zip"} and returns {"file1.txt", "file2.txt"}).
So, the given sub-route looks like this:

```
from("direct:...")
  // FOR EACH FILE NAME
    // APPLY TRANSFORMATION LOGIC TO THE CORRESPONDING FILE
  
  .setBody( // UPDATED LIST OF FILE NAMES )
```

Is it correct to end a route without a producer EIP? Or am I supposed to end it with the *to()* which generates the given new file? If so, it would be mandatory for the next sub-route to read all data again from the very same directory, and that doesn't seem so optimized, since I already know which files have to be taken into consideration.

**Third question**: supposing it's ok to let the given sub-route transform data and return the corresponding names list, how am I supposed to test it? It wouldn't be possible to mock the ending producer, since I'm not completing the route with a producer... so, do I have to use interceptors? Or what else?

Basically, I'm making this question because I have a perfectly working set of routes but, during tests creation, I've noticed that some of them are unnatural to test... and this could easily be the result of a wrong design.

Answer (score 1):

1. enrich is used if you want/need to integrate external data into your route
2. The example below illustrates how you could load the actual list of file types from an external file, where the aggregation strategy will add the file types to the exchange header. Afterwards a split is performed on the enriched header and the exchange directed to the respective route (or an error is thrown if no route is available for the file type). This route makes use of the [enrich EIP](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/enrich-eip.html), the [split EIP](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/split-eip.html) and [content based routing](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/content-based-router-eip.html).

```java
from(...)
    .enrich("file:loadFileList", aggregationStrategy)
    .split(header("fileList").tokenize(","))
    .to("direct:routeContent");

from("direct:routeContent")
    .choice()
        .when(header("fileList").isEqualTo("..."))
            .to("direct:storeFile")
        .when(header("fileList").isEqualTo("..."))
            .to("direct:unzip")
        .when(header("fileList").isEqualTo("..."))
            ...
        .default()
            .throw(...)
    .end()

from("direct:storeFile")
    .to("file:destination");

from("direct:unzip")
    .split(new ZipSplitter())
        .streaming().convertBodyTo(String.class)
        .choice()
            .when(body().isNotNull())
                .to("file:destination")
            .default()
                .throw(...)
        .end()
    .end()
```

The corresponding aggregation strategy might look something like this:

```java
public class FileListAggregationStrategy implements AggregationStrategy {
  
    @Override
    public Exchange aggregate(Exchange original, Exchange resource) {
        String content = resource.getIn().getBody(String.class);
        origina.setHeader("fileList", content);
    }
}
```

Note however, that I have not tested the code myself. I just wrote down a basic structure mostly on top of my head.

> Is it correct to end a route without a producer EIP

AFAIK Camel should "tell you" (in the sense of an error) that no producer is available when you attempt to load the route. A simple `.log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, "...")` however is enough to stop Camel complaining if I remember correctly (haven't worked with Camel in a while now).

3. You always have the possibility to weave certain routes using `AdviceRouteBuilder` and modify routes to your needs. The intercepter itself also acts on certain route definitions, such as `.to(...)` i.e. The easiest way to test routes is to use `MockEndpoint`s and replace the final producer calls (i.e. `.to("file:destination")` with your mock endpoint and perform your assertions on it. In the above mentioned sample you could i.e. only test the final unzipping route by providing the `ProducerTemplate` with the respective ZIP archive as body and replace the `.to("file:destination")` with a mock endpoint you perform assertions against. You could also send a single ZIP archive to the `direct:routeContent` and pass along a `fileList` header with the respective name so that the routing should invoke the unzip route. Here you could either reuse the above modified `direct:unzip` route definition and thus also check whether the archive could be unzipped or you could replace the `.to("direct:unzip")` route invocation with an other mock endpoint and such.